# working on a website with Book Module in Drupal 7 bartik theme

Tags: theming

I have a few questions: Using Drupal 7 , bartik theme Book module

1. I want each user to **see the previous weight field** when he wants to add a new page in a book so that they can put the weight by increasing one and it can be organized well. I wanted the body to display this but don't know how to get the values as it will be progressive and different for each book.
2. In spite of enabling contact form in module and adding my category and in Main menu, the **contact form is not seen** when clicked in menu item.
3. There is a **Add new comment** in the main content area which is not visible in the structure, blocks region so **do not know where to control it** from as the comments once posted are seen with the book page and sometimes not.
4. How to make the site more presentable as there is **no place to change the appearance of the content area** e.g to add a border to the main content area, or to centrally align the content, or change the color of the area where there is just the main content. I tried changing the color in the appearance and it changed the whole display area next to the sidebars and the middle area in all.
5. Also Is there any way I can **align the book pages alphabetically** as per the title?
6. I have the Book navigation bar put in the first sidebar and was wondering, what happens when the **number of books increases than the display area**? Does a scrollbar appear automatically?
7. I am also wondering if I should deploy the site which is still locally being made and **add the changes in the hosted site**? But there is a upgrade waiting but it does not allow me to upgrade as it is not available this time. Should i upgrade and then deploy? Will I have to make the changes I have made in certain files, do one more time after upgrading as the files will change too?

Thank you and I appreciate the time you will put into looking into this matter.***Also u can always pick a question and answer that alone.***
Urvashi